# Alarm triggered immediately

Tags: android

Alarm Manager triggers the alarm as soon as the alarm is activated, instead of waiting for the set time. I have followed the suggestions provided by the two answers found at the following site, in order to delay the alarm, but they do not appear to work consistently. Indeed, after successively trying each solution, they initially appeared to work (unless I had made an error...) on the day I had tried them, but no longer worked afterwards.

[Site with 2 Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195187/alarm-manager-is-triggered-immediately-in-android)

Here is the code for my latest trial. I am adding 5 minutes to the current time for delaying the alarm, for testing purposes. (The repeating alarm is supposed to trigger again, 24 hours afterwards, after the initial trigger that is supposed to occur in 5 minutes from now, but occurs immediately instead.)

```
        if (calendar.before(cal_now)) {// Increment if Time is in the past
        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60*60*24*1000, alarmIntentMain);
    }
```

Comment: Add a day, not five minutes, if the alarm time is before the current time - `calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`.

Comment: Thank you Mike. That is indeed my intention. But I am adding 5 minutes only for testing purposes. Shouldn't this also work?

Comment: Why? That doesn't really make any sense. If the alarm time is, for example, two hours before now, it's still going to fire immediately after adding five minutes, because the alarm time will still be one hour and fifty-five minutes in the past.

Comment: Wait a second. Are you trying to trigger the first alarm five minutes from now, regardless of the current time? Or are you trying to set the alarm at a specific time of day?

Comment: Thank you again Mike. I am trying to set it at a specific time, but triggering it in 5 minutes from now for testing purposes. Within the App, yes, this wouldn't make sense, as you mentioned. But for testing purposes, shouldn't the alarm initially trigger at the time specified in calendar.getTimeInMillis(), which would be 5 minutes later in this case? Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: I don't know how you're setting your `calendar`, so I don't know when five minutes added to that will be. I would also mention that the `setRepeating()` method is inexact, so it might be a bit off.

Comment: I am setting it at the current time, and adding 5 minutes. Yes, I understand that the setRepeating() method is not exact, but I would think that it shouldn't trigger 5 minutes before the set time (in this case now + 5). Thank you again.

Comment: OK, but I'm not really sure how exactly you're "setting it at the current time". `Calendar.getInstance()` will return an instance with the current time already set, so you don't really need to set anything yourself. If you want a relatively definitive test to see if it is the inexact nature of that method that's the issue, omit your `calendar` for now, and just use `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 5 * 60 * 1000` for that argument.

Comment: Thank you for your time Mike. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Whoops. I just realized what I wrote there. I actually meant  to say `System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 60 * 1000`, but they're basically the same thing. Either way would work for your test.

Answer (score 0):

There's a known issue in Lollipop that the AlarmManager will trigger immediately just after it has set. I faced this issue even using JobScheduler.

[Here's the reported bug.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37014472)